# Extjs 5 hasMany vs field.reference

Tags: extjs, reference, associations, difference, extjs5

I'm struggling to understand the different types of data bindings in ExtJS and I couldn't figure this out:

What is the difference between "hasMany" and "field.reference" when defining associations on two models?

When should I use "hasMany" and when is "reference" better?

For example, if I want to define multiple email addresses to one user, what is the best practice so I can use the email model elsewhere too?

I'm aware that I have 3 questions, but these seem to belong together.

Thanks!

Comment: I'd say hasMany will not survive into ExtJS 6.

Comment: I am in the same situation. Right now hasMany doesn't seem to work properly in ExtJS 5.0.1

Comment: @benoror there have certainly been issues with it that have continued into 5.1.1

Answer (score 9, accepted):

One of the best breakdowns on this I've seen is here:

https://moduscreate.com/blog/associations-in-ext-js-5/

It goes into a lot of detail, and specifically addresses your third question regarding email addresses - because the association is now defined on the child model rather than parent model, you have to have a different email model if you want to attach it to a different parent, i.e. a CustomerEmail class to attach to Customer and an AdminEmail class to attach to Admin.

There's a bit of detail for the reason for the change here:

http://www.sencha.com/blog/deep-dive-into-ext-js-5-data

> Declaring associations is another area in Ext JS 5 where we have
> reduced boilerplate code requirements. In previous releases, the
> hasMany, hasOne and belongsTo configs required that you manually
> maintain symmetric declarations on both “sides” of an association.
> This is no longer the case. You can declare an association in either
> of the associated classes (though typically on the “many” side).

Comment: I just stumbled upon that Modus Create resource. It's pretty great.